# How to search a character backwards from the end of line in Vim

Tags: vim

for the example text below, the curser is in the first space:

> This is the sentence.

is it awesome that I can use command like

`fe`

to jump to the last e in the end of the line

but unfortunately f and F only can search according to the current cursor position, Is there a command that I can search a character backwards from the end of line?

Comment: `$Fe` dollar to go to the end of the line?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `$` to go to the end of the line. And then you can do a `F` from there to search backwards.

You can use `0` to go to the beginning of the line (first non whitespace). And then you can use `f` to search forwards.

`$F` search backwards from end of line.
`0f` search forwards from beginning of line.

Comment: thanks! But I a vim script to automate this process would be better

Comment: @yozloy you could use a mapping `nnoremap <leader>F $F` but I'm not sure if this will by you anything as I don't thin there are that many (if any) single character mappings that you will want to override.

Comment: You can also reverse a single character search with `,`. So if you skip over the spot you are trying to get to, you can jump back. (Note that some vim setups use `,` as the leader key so you will get a slight delay for the reverse to happen).